# Java Throwing exception in child constructor on super attribute

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, exception, constructor

I have an abstract class with a constructor that throws no exception and a class that extends it, but that is supposed to throw a generic exception in the constructor.

For the exception to be thrown I need to check an attribute from the parent class (which I can't do before the super() call).

Is there a way to make this possible without throwing an exception in the parent class or is that the best approach?

Comment: Why can't you throw the exception _after_ the call to `super()` ?

Comment: Wouldn't that initialize my object anyway?

Comment: If your object is partially initialised (by the superclass constructor), and then throws an exception (in the subclass constructor) it is unusable because construction did not complete successfully. You are allowed to throw exceptions in subclass constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the super(); call has to be first. If you don't specify the call explicitly, it is done implicitly. That means the parent constructor will complete before your child constructor does anything else. After that, your child class may throw an exception based on anything done in the parent constructor. It sounds like you are making this harder than it is...